# Python: 2.5.1 Painting a Wall

Tags: python

I am currently trying to solve this on python. Here's where I've got to so far:

350 square feet requires 1 gallon of paint. Assign gallons_paint with the amount of paint required for wall_area. Sample output for the given program:

```
250.0 square feet wall will need:
0.714285714286 gallons of paint

wall_area = 250.0
gallons_paint = 0.0

gallons_paint = 0.714285714286

print(wall_area, 'square feet wall will need:')
print(gallons_paint, 'gallons of paint')
```

Comment: What is tripping you up? The math, or the code?

Comment: It's the code, I am able to pass the first test but for the second part not so much. This is what I am getting back:Testing with wall_area 250.0
Your output
0.7142857142857143
clear
Testing with wall_area 578.6
Your output
0.714285714286
Expected output
1.6531428571428572

Comment: I don't know what to do with the wall area of 578.6 or where it even came from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something here, but if 350 sq ft requires 1 gallon, then 250 sq ft will require 250/350 gallons. So you are being asked (I suppose) to request the area from the user and calculate the paint required for that area.

```
wall_area=float(input("How big is your wall in square feet? "))
gallons_paint = wall_area / 350
print(wall_area, 'square feet wall will need:')
print(gallons_paint, 'gallons of paint')
```

For example,

```
How big is your wall in square feet? 250
250.0 square feet wall will need:
0.7142857142857143 gallons of paint
```

Though you really ought to format the number to something sensible, as in

```
print(f'{gallons_paint:.2f} gallons of paint')
```

which will report

```
0.71 gallons of paint
```

With your other number, 576.6 square feet,

```
How big is your wall in square feet? 578.6
578.6 square feet wall will need:
1.65 gallons of paint
```

Comment: gallons_paint = wall_area / 350 solved it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite simple problem.

The question gives you the ratio need to construct your program. `1` gallon of paint every `350` square feet. Thus, to find the amount of paint need to paint `x` square feet, you need to use the equation:

```
   350        area
 -------  = ------- = 350x = area (or area/350)
    1          x
```

Using the above equation, we then write out the code:

```
area = int(input('Input the surface area: '))
print('The amount of paint needed is: ', area / 350)
```

If you want to control how many decimals places are displayed, you can string formatting:

```
print('The amount of paint needed is: {0:.<prec>f}'.format(area / 350))
```

Where `<prec>` is the desired amount of precision.

Answer (score 0):

this could be useful:

```
wall_area = 250.0

gallons_paint = 0.0

gallons_paint = wall_area/350.0

print(wall_area, 'square feet wall will need:')

print(gallons_paint, 'gallons of paint')
```

Comment: Please take some minute to describe what your answer does. It could be more useful for everybody

Answer (score 0):

[my guess][1]

```
 wall_area = float(input())
 s_wall_area = wall_area / 350.0
 final = (f'{s_wall_area:.5f}')
print(final)
```

both test passed

Answer (score -2):

This is all you need:

```
gallons_paint = 0.0
wall_area = float(input())
# Assign gallons_paint below
gallons_paint = 350.0
gallons_paint = wall_area/350.0
print(gallons_paint)
```

Testing with wall_area input 250.0
Your value
0.7142857142857143

Testing with wall_area input 578.6
Your value
1.6531428571428572

Comment: Your answer is non-sensical.  gallons_paint is assigned three values with no intervening logic